# More Efficient Code Than Using If Statements

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, performance

I am currently in the process of making an iOS app will Objective-C. I have a lot of if statements that are making UIImageView appear in my app. Is there a more efficient way to do it or should I keep all my if statements?

Thanks

***EDIT*** See code below:

```
if (obscacle.center.x < 0) {
    randomPosition = arc4random() %20;
    randomPosition = randomPosition + 110;
    obscacle.center = CGPointMake(568, randomPosition);
}

if (obscacle2.center.x < 0) {
    randomPosition = arc4random() %20;
    randomPosition = randomPosition + 110;
    obscacle2.center = CGPointMake(568, randomPosition);
}


if (top1.center.x < -50) {
    randomPosition = arc4random() %20;
    top1.center = CGPointMake(550, randomPosition);
    randomPosition = randomPosition + 265;
    bottom1.center = CGPointMake(568, randomPosition);
}

if (top2.center.x < -50) {
    randomPosition = arc4random() %20;
    top2.center = CGPointMake(550, randomPosition);
    randomPosition = randomPosition + 265;
    bottom2.center = CGPointMake(568, randomPosition);
}

if (top3.center.x < -55) {
    randomPosition = arc4random() %20;
    top3.center = CGPointMake(550, randomPosition);
    randomPosition = randomPosition + 265;
    bottom3.center = CGPointMake(568, randomPosition);
}

if (top3.center.x < -55) {
    randomPosition = arc4random() %20;
    top3.center = CGPointMake(550, randomPosition);
    randomPosition = randomPosition + 265;
    bottom3.center = CGPointMake(568, randomPosition);
}

if (top4.center.x < -55) {
    randomPosition = arc4random() %20;
    top4.center = CGPointMake(550, randomPosition);
    randomPosition = randomPosition + 265;
    bottom4.center = CGPointMake(568, randomPosition);
}

if (top5.center.x < -55) {
    randomPosition = arc4random() %20;
    top5.center = CGPointMake(550, randomPosition);
    randomPosition = randomPosition + 265;
    bottom5.center = CGPointMake(568, randomPosition);
}

if (top6.center.x < -55) {
    randomPosition = arc4random() %20;
    top6.center = CGPointMake(550, randomPosition);
    randomPosition = randomPosition + 265;
    bottom6.center = CGPointMake(568, randomPosition);
}

if (top7.center.x < -55) {
    randomPosition = arc4random() %20;
    top7.center = CGPointMake(568, randomPosition);
    randomPosition = randomPosition + 265;
    bottom7.center = CGPointMake(568, randomPosition);
}
```

Comment: post your code then is to be easily to answer for folks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very difficult to say without seeing your code but for some reasons sometimes switch statement is better replacement.

Example:

```
switch (expression)
 {
     case match1:
          statements
          break;

     case match2:
          statements
          break;

     default:
          statements
          break;
 }
```

All depends what are you trying to do.

Comment: I just made an edit with my code... Thanks for the reply though

Comment: For your example I think you should stick with if, you can move randomPosition = arc4random() %20; on the top before if statement and remove from the condition because you all the same for each single if.

Comment: @Greg No, Greg - moving `randomPosition = arc4random() %20` to the top would change the code, since it has "side effects"  ;)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you need a few for loops.

Pseudocode:

```
for each obstacle in [array of obstacles]:
    if (obscacle.center.x < 0):
        randomPosition = arc4random() %20
        randomPosition = randomPosition + 110
        obscacle.center = CGPointMake(568, randomPosition)
```

And ditto for the "top"s.

Do note that this isn't about efficiency so much as making your code neater and more maintainable. In terms of performance, either approach should be more than acceptable for your use case.

Comment: Totally agree: _"Do note that this isn't about efficiency so much as making your code neater and more maintainable."_ For what's worth, this is the actual problem of the OPs question and thus, the only correct answer ;)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Unless there are tons of obstacles, if vs switch has no efficiency impact whatsoever. But maintainability suffers greatly from heaps of if statements that could be replaced by a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may be able to eliminate the if statements completely.

You say you're using the if to select which image to show. So if you name the image based on the variable you're testing in the if, you could instead use that variable to just select the right name.